# Celery task bad return when using update_state

Tags: django, celery, djcelery

I have a celery task which updates it's state multiple times while it's running with:

```
current_task.update_state(state='STARTED', meta={'doing': "some message"},)
```

When this task returns:

```
return row  # row is a Django model instance
```

The return value I get:

```
>> res = task_above.delay()
>> res.result
u'16'
```

is only the object's id as a string, not the pickled object itself.

If i remove the update_state statements, I get the correct pickled object in the task's meta (AsyncResult.result)

How can I use update_state and get the same return value (pickled object)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that you can get a pickled django model instance at all, considering pickle only supports python primitives. Are you absolutely sure that you are ever getting the django model instance as a pickled result? maybe it's not going thru celery and it's not pickled?

see [this SO answer] for more about pickling django model instances[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011474/how-do-i-pickle-instances-of-django-models-in-a-database-into-sample-python-co).