# Archiving Django models

Tags: python, django, cron, foreign-keys

I'm creating an online order system for selling items on a regular basis (home delivery of vegetable boxes). I have an 'order' model (simplified) as follows:

```
class BoxOrder(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    frequency = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, "Weekly"), (2, "Fortnightly)))
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    payment_method = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, "Online"), (2, "Free)))
```

Now my 'customer' has the ability to change the frequency of the order, or the 'item' (say 'carrots') being sold or even delete the order all together.

What I'd like to do is create weekly 'backups' of all orders processed that week, so that I can see a historical graph of all the orders ever sold every week. The problem with just archiving the order into another table/database is that if an item (say I no longer sell carrots) is deleted for some reason, then that archived BoxOrder would become invalid because of the `ForeignKeys`

What would be the best solution for creating an archiving system using Django - so that orders for every week in history are viewable in Django admin, and they are 'static' (i.e. independent of whether any other objects are deleted)?
I've thought about creating a new 'flat' `BoxOrderArchive` model, then using a cron job to move orders for a given week over, e.g.:

```
class BoxOrderArchive(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    frequency = models.IntegerField()
    item_name = models.CharField() # refers to BoxOrder.item.name
    item_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2) # refers to BoxOrder.item.price
    payment_method = models.IntegerField()
```

But I feel like that might be a lot of extra work. Before I go down that route, it would be great to know if anybody has any other solutions?

Thanks

Comment: My share is that without creating a similar table, it will be difficult to manage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after looking into this long and hard, I think the best solution for me is to create a 'flat' version of the object, dereferencing any existing objects, and save that in the database.

The reason for this is that my 'BoxOrder' object can change every week (as the customer edits their address, item, cost etc. Keeping track of all these changes is just plain difficult.
Plus, I don't need to do anything with the data other than display it to the sites users.

Basically what I am wanting to do is to create a snapshot, and none of the existing tools really are what I want. Having said that, others may have different priorities, so here's a list of useful links:

[1] [SO question regarding storing a snapshot/pickling model instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011474/how-do-i-pickle-instances-of-django-models-in-a-database-into-sample-python-co)

[2] [Django Simple History Docs](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - stores model state on every create/update/delete

[3] [Django Reversion Docs](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) - allows reverting a model instance

For discussion on [2] and [3], see the comments on Serafim's answer

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather broad topic, and I won't specifically answer your question, however my advice to you is *don't delete or move anything*. You can add a boolan field to your `Item` named `is_deleted` or `is_active` or something similar and play with that flag when you delete your item. This way you can

- keep your `ForeignKey`s,
- have a different representation for non-active items
- restore and `Item` that was previously deleted (for instance you may want to sell Carrots again after some months - this way your statistics will be consistent across the year)

The same advice is true for the `BoxOrder` model. Do not remove rows to different tables, just add an `is_archived` field and set it to `True`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had considered this idea, but the problem is quite a bit more complex. Not actually deleting the `BoxOrder` item doesn't store its *history*. The thing is, a `BoxOrder` item can change over time so what I really need are snapshots every week -ideally with Foreign Keys still in place of course.

Comment: I still don't see why you need to actually *delete* rows from your database. For the history of objects I'd recommend a solution like https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history (if you want to also actually query the snapshots - since the fields are copied as is) or https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion (if you just want to be able to see or restore the older versions of the object)

Comment: Yes, I've *just* found django-simple-history, I was thinking; using that+`is_deleted` would do the trick. django-reversion seems like another option. Better docs, but it looks like revisions are only saved when editing through the admin interface. The only downside to using `is_deleted` is that I can't use Django's `DeleteView`, which is a (very small) downside

Comment: You can of course implement your own DeleteView. Also, django reversion *works* outside of the admin -- you just need to add ``reversion.middleware.RevisionMiddleware`` to your ``MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`` (and of course inherit your Admin class from ``reversion.VersionAdmin``)

Comment: Just also like to point out that while the solution of using a boolean field works, it's a bit messy to the table and isn't necessarily normalized. However, applications do have priorities so I guess it's a personal preference if you want to keep that data denormalized.